# What determines the application name when pinned to taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a solution named "NameLastname.Vulcanus" containing a single WPF project "NameLastname.Vulcanus.WindowsDesktop".

In this project, the *Assembly name*, *Default namespace*, as well as the following Assembly Information fields: *Title* and *Product* are all identical to the project name, "NameLastname.Vulcanus.WindowsDesktop".

However, when I run the application, pin it to the taskbar, then close it, the tooltip (as well as the shortcut name) show "NameLastName.Vulcanus", which only seems to correspond to the solution name. I couldn't ctrl+f this exact string anywhere else in the solution.

Additionally, when I tried to create a new project to isolate the issue, I couldn't reproduce the exact conditions, as the application name started corresponding to the *project* name (but I still couldn't get it to change using the fields mentioned above).

What's going on?

Comment: The "Window Title" affects the Taskbar Name. Change the Window Title to something more friendly.

Comment: @user2864740: That applies only for when the application is running. My question is about when it's closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the application displayed in taskabar is determined by the name which is set in a link which is pinned or displayed in a taskbar. On the other hand name of the link is the same as the name of the executable assembly (exe file) which starts your application unless it was registered with other name during installation.

To have a full control over it create a simple installer and install your app in controlled way. One of the most important function provided by installer is a detailed control over content, location and graphics used in application links. WiX toolset is an easy to use installer framework which is open source and has good support/documentation and it is integrated with Visual Studio.

It is possible to verify above by right clicking on an taskbar icon until it will show dropdawn and then right clicking again on an application icon. In opened window in a General tab there is field which contains displayed application name i.e. executable of Visual Studio is a devenv.exe while display name is Visual Studio 2017 Community. All this features are controlled via registry as well but there is no need to go that deep.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So what you're saying is that it for falls outside of the scope of the assembly, and is handled during deployment.

Comment: But one thing doesn't sit right with me. WiX can control how a shortcut is created during installation, but will it still work if I don't create one myself and a user decides to pin the app itself later on?

Comment: No, the name of the application in the shortcut will be just a name of the executable. Try it yourself - go to Visual Studio installation folder and right click executable i.e. devenv.exe and you will get shortcut with devenv.exe name. Usually users pinning apps to start, dekstop or taskbar click another link to application created during installation and this just works.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! :)